# how to split and get the first date and time in excel

Tags: excel

I have the date and time in a cell. Where all the dates with time are merged together. I want to split that and get the output of the first date and time,  as expected output below in Excel

Current output :

```
28/Sep/2020 08:29/Sep/2020 13:32
28/Sep/2020 11:129/Sep/2020 13:19
30/Sep/2020 08:01/Oct/2020 12:29
```

Expected output:

```
28/Sep/2020 08:29
28/Sep/2020 11:12
30/Sep/2020 08:01
```

Comment: Use find() to get the position of the 3rd / and then left() and right() for the rest. Look on here as there are many examples of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+5)
```

[image]

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("!",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","!",3))-1)
```

28/Sep/2020 11:12`9`/Sep/2020 13:19

Number 9 is mistakenly entered it?